# Pods from a private repo are not found by CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I can't use a pod from a private cocoapods repo.

When I try to add my pod, using version 0.37.1, I get the following error:

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for ...
```

My cocoapods configuration is using 2 remotes:

```
$ pod repo list 

bootstragram-public-pod-repo
- Type: git (master)
- URL:  https://github.com/Bootstragram/bootstragram-public-pod-repo.git
- Path: /Users/mick/.cocoapods/repos/bootstragram-public-pod-repo

master
- Type: git (master)
- URL:  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
- Path: /Users/mick/.cocoapods/repos/master

2 repos
```

And when I use `pod install --verbose`, it seems that only the `master` repo is checked, not the private one:

```
  Preparing
    Migrating to CocoaPods 0.36

Analyzing dependencies

Updating spec repositories
Updating spec repo `master`
  ...

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods`: (``)

...

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
Finished resolution (0 steps) (Took 0.455585 seconds) (2015-05-13 15:09:23 +0200)
[!] Unable to find a specification for `BSGUtilities`
```

I wish there was a `Updating spec repo bootstragram-public-pod-repo` :)

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does your Podfile include all your [sources](https://github.com/artsy/eigen/blob/master/Podfile#L1-L2) e.g. a reference to the other Specs repo?

From [Artsy/Eigen](https://github.com/artsy/eigen/)

```
  source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

Comment: I hope people visiting this page will thank me for being so dumb. :) Thanks @orta!

Comment: Not dumb, just probably hadn't found the right bit of a guide somewhere. Not a problem at all.